# Explaining Windows command

Tags: windows, cmd

What does the following Windows command do?

```
net user some_username>nul 2>&1 && goto :user_exists || goto :user_doesnt_exists
```

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

`net user some_username`  show properties of the user "some_username"

`>nul 2>&1` redirect STDOUT and STDERR to NUL (don't show any output)
(We don't need the actual output, we only want to know, if the `net user` command was successful or not (user exists or not))

`&& goto :user_exists`  `&&` means "if previous command was successful, then do ..."

`|| goto :user_doesnt_exists` `||`means "if previous command was NOT successful, then do ..."